# Как реализовать FileObserver на java в Android?

Tags: java, android

Пробую создать простой FileObserver. Сервис запускается и работает, но события не приходят. Разрешение READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE есть.

```
public class MyService extends Service {
public MyService() {
}

public static FileObserver observer;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    final String pathToWatch = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/DCIM/Camera/";
    File file = new File(pathToWatch);
    Log.i("MyService", "My Service Started and trying to watch " + pathToWatch);

    observer = new FileObserver(file,FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS) { 
        @Override
        public void onEvent(int event, String file) {
            Log.i("MyService", "File created");
        }
    };
    observer.startWatching();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    //TODO for communication return IBinder implementation
    return null;
}
```

запускаю вот так

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                },
                1);
    } else {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        this.startService(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте передавать не файл, но `file.getCanonicalPath()`

Comment: вы имеете ввиду в конструктор передать строку, а не файл? Такой конструктор устарел, судя по офф документации. И я это пробовала) Передавала observer = new FileObserver(pathToWatch,FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS)

Comment: Я просто где-то видел, что люди пишут, что Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() возвращает символическую ссылку на папку, а FileObserver в неё не умеет. Но, может, это и не так. ВОзможно у вас проблема с доступом к внешней относительно приложения папке из-за новых правил андроида с 9-10 версии ОС. Попробуйте отслеживать внутреннюю папку приложения с вашим кодом - возможно, оно заработает. Если дело в этом, то вам надо будет запрашивать на новых версиях ОС специальное временное разрешение на доступ к внешней памяти. Проверить это можно и запустив код на старых версиях ОС (5-8)

Comment: хм, попробую покапать в эту сторону. Разрешения запрашиваю динамически, с этим норм всё, вроде if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    },
                    1);
        } else {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
            this.startService(intent);
        }

Comment: Этих разрешений недостаточно для версий ОС 10+ (может и 9). Работа с файловой системой сильно изменена. На какой версии ОС тестируете?

Comment: на 10. Спасибо!!)) нужно было добавить android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

Comment: Пожалуйста) Но вам надо понимать, что `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` - временное решение и вам надо бы от него избавиться, если приложение планируете в PlayMarket выкладывать - его в определённый момент просто могут туда не пустить и надо будет, вроде, запрашивать у тех.поддержки гугла разрешение на доступ к файловой системе и/или таки реализовать явный запрос разрешения у юзера на доступ к строго определённой папке. Или, если задача позволяет - использовать внутреннюю папку приложения - там вообще никаких разрешений не нужно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а что, есть способ запросить доступ к папке и работать с ней через `java.io/nio`? Или вы имеете в виду `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` и т.д.?

Comment: Я точно не знаю как, но в документации вроде что то про это было)